# Need I export all functions in Erlang shell?

Tags: erlang

I have these code

```
start() ->
    spawn(?MODULE, init, [self()]).

init(From) ->
    spawn(?MODULE, broadcast, []).    

broadcast() ->
    Msg = "helloworld",
    timer:sleep(10000),
    broadcast().
```

When I test these code in Erlang shell, it give me undef error, I need to export broadcast function, I am just refuse

Comment: As written you need to export both the `start/0` function so it can be called and the `init/1` function. When you spawn a function with `spawn/3` as you have done then that function must also be exported. An alternative is to spawn a fun as others have suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code

```
spawn(?MODULE, init, [self()]).
```

means you will spawn process which initial call will be `?MODULE:init(self())` or more precisely equivalent of `apply(?MODULE,init,[self()])`. `?MODULE` is macro evaluated to current module name but anyway It is external function call so this function have to be exported even there is `?MODULE` used. In contrary

```
spawn(fun() -> init(self()) end).
```

is spawn with initial call to the func `fun() -> init(self()) end` which calls `init/1` with result of function `self()`. It is local call which means `init/1` may not be exported. There is another issue with it when `self()` is performed inside new process so you have to write

```
Self = self(), spawn(fun() -> init(Self) end).
```

to achieve same effect as in `spawn(?MODULE, init, [self()])` where `self()` is evaluated as parameter of `spawn/3`.

Comment: Good answer: Self = self(), spawn(fun() -> init(Self) end).

Answer (score 1):

well, the function `broadcast` is executed in a process. This function must therefore be accessible to all processes. Even though the same piece of source code, in the same module, spawns a process which goes to execute a function from the same module, that function must be exported out of that module to make it accessible.

That brings me to the difference between `spawn(fun() -> broadcast() end).` and `spawn(?MODULE, broadcast, [])`. The later is called `Spawning with MFA`. In this method, the function must be exported out of the module so that it can be executed. The former is however unique, its a `fun`.

To understand this method: `spawn(fun() -> broadcast() end).`, we need to compare it with this one: `spawn(fun() -> ?MODULE:broadcast() end).` . Now, lets talk about the later of the two

---

**`spawn(fun() -> ?MODULE:broadcast() end).`**
 Now, here, if the function `broadcast` IS NOT exported in the module: `?MODULE`, the process will crash. Note that in this case, the function is in the very module in which this piece of source code is written.

---

**`spawn(fun() -> broadcast() end).`**
In this case, the function must be in the very module in which this piece of source code is written. However, my thinking is this, the compiler converts this to the one above so that the spawned process is told that the function you are looking for is in module `?MODULE`.
I am not really a guru at compilers or run time systems, but i guess you will use this answer. My Strong advice is that in most of your source code, use this `spawn(fun() -> ?MODULE:broadcast() end).` or `spawn(fun() -> some_module:broadcast() end).` even though the piece of code or the function resides in that same very module than this: <strike>`spawn(fun() -> broadcast() end).`</strike>. From my personal experience the code becomes manageable and understandable. I get this nice illusion that a spawned process has to go and find the function from the specified module, and then execute with the given arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Look more carefully at the warnings:

```
test.erl:8: Warning: function init/1 is unused
test.erl:8: Warning: variable 'From' is unused
test.erl:11: Warning: function broadcast/0 is unused
test.erl:12: Warning: variable 'Msg' is unused
```

The compiler thinks that your other functions are unused and never compiles them. Try this instead:

```
start() ->
    spawn(fun() -> init(self()) end).

init(From) ->
    spawn(fun() -> broadcast() end).
```

Comment: What is the difference between "spawn(?MODULE, broadcast, [])" and "spawn(fun() -> broadcast() end)."  ?